# Trying to implement the difference formula in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, difference, derivative, approximation

Im trying to implement the difference formula

```
f'(x) ≈ [ f(x+h) - f(x) ] / h
```

using MATLAB for `x=1` and `h=10^-k`, where `k=0,...,16`. Furthermore, I want to plot the error.

Below is my code. I see that the error is around 3, which I believe it too big. It should be close to 0.

```
syms f(x)
f(x) = tan(x);
df = diff(f,x);
x = 1;
for k = 0:16
    h = 10^-k;
    finitediff = double((f(x+h)-f(x))/h);
    err = double(abs(finitediff-df(x)));
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing wrong in your code, the finite difference formula works just well, and the error you get lies in compute items following numerically:

- errs generated by calculating `a/b` when both `a` and `b` are very very small.
- calculating `a-b` when `a` and `b` are very very close that MATLAB will give `0`.

Here is the result when k changes from 1 to 15:

[image]

Thanks @CrisLuengo 's insightful comment!

which shows that `err` drops to nearly zero instantly, and rise again when `h` becomes `1e-9`(situation 1 happens after this). Finally `df` becomes 0 when `h` becomes `1e-14`(situation 2 happens here).

I added few lines of code to yours to show this:

```
clc;
clear;
format long
syms f(x)
f(x) = tan(x);
h=1;
df = diff(f,x);
double(df(1));
x=1;


range=1:15;
[finitediff,err]=deal(zeros(size(range)));
for k=range
    h=10^-k;
    finitediff(k)=double((f(x+h)-f(x))/h);
    err(k)=double(abs(finitediff(k)-df(1)));
end

figure(1)

subplot(1,2,1)
hold on
plot(err)
plot(err,'bx')
set(gca,'yscale','log')
title('err')

subplot(1,2,2)
hold on
ezplot(df)
axis([0.5 1.5 0 5])
plot(ones(size(range)),finitediff,'rx','MarkerSize',7)
for ii=range
  text(1,finitediff(ii),['h=1e-' num2str(ii)])
end
```

Comment: Nice plots! At 10^-13, the error increases a little already, so the last two dots before the big jump are already increasing. You can see this with `set(gca,'yscale','log')`. Actually I see a minimum at `k=8`.

Answer (score 4):

You are computing `x+h` numerically. with `x=1`, the smallest number larger than `x` that you can make is `x+eps(x) = 1+eps(1)`. `eps(1)` is `2.2204e-16`. So adding `h=1e-16` doesn't change `x`. Now, you are symbolically computing `tan(1)-tan(1)`, which is 0. Hence your finite difference approximation to the derivative is 0.

But even with a larger `h` you get differences of 0. I believe this is because of rounding errors that occur in computing the tangent. Note that

```
x = 1;
h = 1e-14;
f(x+h)
```

returns `tan(1)`. That is, the symbolic toolbox thinks of 1+1e-14 within the context of the `tan` function as sufficiently close to 1 to warrant rounding. Funnily enough,

```
f(x+h)-f(x)
```

returns 0, whereas

```
tan(x+h)-tan(x)
```

returns `3.4195e-14` (which is close to the expected `3.4255e-14`).

Note that, as you can tell by the [graph that Hunter plots](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54050908/7328782), the best approximation is for `h=10^-8`, as you decrease `h` the rounding errors in `x+h` start to increase (use `set(gca,'yscale','log')` to see this).