# Numerical gradient of a Matlab function evaluated at a certain point

Tags: matlab

I have a Matlab function `G(x,y,z)`. At each given `(x,y,z)`, `G(x,y,z)` is a scalar.  `x=(x1,x2,...,xK)` is a `Kx1` vector.

Let us fix `y,z` at some given values. I would like your help to understand how to compute the derivative of `G` with respect to `xk` evaluated at a certain `x`.

For example, suppose `K=3`

```
function  f= G(x1,x2,x3,y,z)
          f=3*x1*sin(z)*cos(y)+3*x2*sin(z)*cos(y)+3*x3*sin(z)*cos(y);
end
```

How do I compute the derivative of `G(x1,x2,x3,4,3)` wrto `x2` and then evaluate it at `x=(1,2,6)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the  partial derivative of dG/dx2

So the first thing would be getting rid of your fixed variables

```
G2 = @(x2) G(1,x2,6,4,3);
```

The numerical derivatives are finite differences, you need to choose an step `h` for your finite difference, and an [appropriate method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_differentiation)

The simplest one is

```
(G2(x2+h)-G2(x2))/h
```

You can make `h` as small as your numeric precision allows you to. At the limit `h -> 0` the finite difference is the partial derivative

Comment: As an addendum, these answers provide some insight into choosing the right *h*: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54049833/trying-to-implement-the-difference-formula-in-matlab/54050959